# Automatically set up Outlook Profile for new user

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, active-directory

I'm a part of a small IT team for a medium sized business.

When we set up a new user, we usually create an email account and set their password up, we never give email passwords out for security reasons.

We have a external office with users that Hot desk, meaning that we need to set up the new user on every machine and set up the Outlook account manually. This is done over Remote Support.

Is there anyway that the Outlook account sets up automatically by fetching the details from AD or setting up some kind of group policy for this?

We have users set up on either Windows 7, 8, 8.1 or 10 although we need to start using one version of OS to avoid confusion. All users have Outlook 2013 installed.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know... Seems like too much of a pain. Have them use Outlook for Web Access instead. Otherwise, you have to set up a separate profile for each user on every workstation? http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/deployprf.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know it seems like a pain, but it's a pain to set them up individually, especially if we have new users. We would give them access to Web Outlook, however we don't want to share their passwords, or give them the option to change it (as you can on Web Outlook).

I'll have a read of the article you linked.

Comment: I usually dislike passwords you can't change since at least two people know the password and it creates an environment of liability. If someone else can log into my account, I could be blamed for work that I did not perform.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ZeroConfigExchange](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/outlooking/2015/10/30/zeroconfigexchange-automating-the-creation-of-an-outlook-profile-for-exchange-online-accounts-and-exchange-on-premises-environments/):

> 1. In the Windows Registry, navigate to the appropriate subkey for each version of Outlook that is in use:
>      For Outlook 2013:
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
> 2. Once the key is created, right-click in the right pane and click New, click DWORD Value and type in “ZeroConfigExchange” (without the
>      quotes) and then press ENTER.
> 3. Finally, right-click ZeroConfigExchange, click Modify and then in the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.